# Should we be able to vote to move bounty questions to another site?

Tags: discussion, bounties, vote-to-close, migration

Referencing this question on SF:
[**Flash Plugin - How to disable automatic updates on a computer that is offline?**](https://serverfault.com/questions/49447/flash-plugin-how-to-disable-automatic-updates-on-a-computer-that-is-offline)

I would vote close this as "belongs on superuser", but it's got a bounty and as such I can't vote.  Should we be able to vote to move these questions?  Maybe allow only the "belongs on..." votes when a question has a bounty?  Or should something like this just be flagged for moderator's attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably does belong on SU. It had to be sitting around for 2 days before a bounty could be put on it so I'm not sure why it didn't close/move in that time.

Moving a bounty post is... problematic. And it's probably such a corner case that it's not worth dealing with. It can (I assume!) be moved in a week (when the bounty is up). Not sure it requires moderator attention.

Comment: I can dig that.  Bigger fish to fry...  So is the problem in moving bounty question because of the discrepancy in rep between the sites?  I think things sit for a little while longer on SF because there isn't a huge set of users who can vote to close yet (about 39 if I count correct).